# How to remove Sprite when collision is detected? Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision, rectangles

Every random time (between 1,2 and 3 seconds) a rectangle and a sprite is created,1 rectangle for each sprite that spawns.

new enemy method is called at random time:

```
public void newEnemy(){
        Sprite enemy= Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        enemy.set(enemySpr);
        enemy.setPosition(200,150);
        enemies.add(enemy);}
```

the same thing happens to rectangles:

```
 public void newRect(){
        Rectangle rect=Pools.obtain(Rectangle.class);
        rect.set(enemyRect);
        rectangles.add(rect);
    }
```

basically when the rectangle and sprite are spawned they move upward,and at the top of the screen there's another rectangle.I wan't the rectangle and sprite to be removed when the collision is detected.

@Tenfour04 I just tried your advice but I still get the error.

```
while (enemyIterator.hasNext()){
            Sprite nextEnemy=enemyIterator.next(); //I get the error here..
           if(enemySpr.getY()+enemySpr.getHeight()>=treeObj.treeSpr.getY()){
               removeEnemy(nextEnemy);
           }
```

@Tenfour04 this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at com.dreamroad.savethetree.EnemyClass.update(EnemyClass.java:66)
    at com.dreamroad.savethetree.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:51)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Didn't I answer this question for you before? See the `removeEnemy()` method in my answer to that question.

Comment: Yes Sir but I get an error, cause the condition there I need is //rect.overlaps(rect). Cause the other Sprite has also a rectangle.

Comment: Not sure why you need a separate rectangle from the sprite. The Sprite already has a rectangle stored in it called `bounds`. I don't really understand your question, but maybe your troubles are because you are using two different object arrays to reference a single list of "things".

Comment: ...and the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the stack trace, on the other side I do not know, that is, removeEnemy (...) and how it works, but maybe this helps:

```
 while (enemyIterator.hasNext()){

     Sprite nextEnemy=enemyIterator.next(); //I get the error here.. -> push stact trace

      if(enemySpr.getY()+enemySpr.getHeight()>=treeObj.treeSpr.getY()){

           enemyIterator.remove();
           //removeEnemy(nextEnemy);
       }
 }
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.